# What should I do when the axios req.body undefined problem occurs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

It was supposed to work, but suddenly from server, req.The body is marked as undefinde.

Body-parser is already in use on the server. It works fine when you send a query to Postman.

There is a problem at the stage of sending from the client to the server.

```js
axios.post(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URI}/auth/signin`,
          {
            username: signinInfo.username,
            password: signinInfo.password,
          },
          { headers: { "Content-Type":"application/json"  },      
        }
        )
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(signinInfo.username);

          localStorage.setItem("accessToken", res.data.accessToken);

          localStorage.setItem(
            "subgatherUserInfo",
            JSON.stringify(res.data.data)
          );

          persistLogin(true);

          //  console.log(mypageOn(disabled) )

          navigate("/");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(signinInfo.password, signinInfo.username);

          // mypageOff()

          mypageOn(false);
          setSigninInfo({ ...signinInfo, password: "" });

          setSigninErrMessage("아이디와 비밀번호를 정확히 입력해주세요");
          //로그인 정보가 맞지 않는경우. errmessage
          throw err;
        });
    }
```

node.js server

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const app = express();
const Port =process.env.PORT|| 5001;
const {authchecker} = require('./middleware/authChecker');
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth')

const userRouter = require('./routes/user');
const walletRouter = require('./routes/wallet')
app.use(express.json()); //미들웨어

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //미들웨어
app.use(cookieParser()); // 미들웨어

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [process.env.CLIENT_URL,"http://localhost:3000"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
    
    
   
//routes


app.use(authchecker)

app.use('/auth',authRouter)
app.use('/user',userRouter)
app.use('/wallet',walletRouter)



// app.get("/", (req, res) => {
//   res.send("Hello Nodes.js");
// });

app.listen(Port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is Startin on ${Port}`);
});
```

login router

```js
signinControl: async (req, res) => {

    const { username, password } = req.body;

  
    try {
      console.log(req.body,'login')
      

      // console.log(username,password)

      const salt = await user.findOne({
        attributes: ["salt"],
        where: { username:username },
      });

      //2. 유저 db에서 이메일 확인하기

      crypto.pbkdf2(
        password,
        salt.dataValues.salt,
        11011,
        64,
        "sha512",
        async (err, key) => {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }
          const hardPassword = key.toString("base64");

          // console.log(hardPassword)
          const getUserInfo = await user.findOne({
            where: { username: username, password: hardPassword },
          });
          console.log(getUserInfo);

          if (!getUserInfo) {
            return res.status(401).send("이메일 및 비밀번호 확인");
          }
          const userUsername = getUserInfo.dataValues.username;
          const userNick = getUserInfo.dataValues.nickname;
          const userId = getUserInfo.dataValues.id;
          const isSocial = getUserInfo.dataValues.social_user;
          const isAdmin = getUserInfo.dataValues.isAdmin
          // const { email, nickname, id } = getUserInfo.dataValues;
          const accessToken = generateAccessToken({
            userUsername,
            userNick,
            userId,
            isAdmin,
            isSocial
          });
          const refreshToken = generateRefreshToken({
            userUsername,
            userNick,
            userId,
            isAdmin,
            isSocial
          });
          const accessExp = tokenExp(accessToken);
          const refreshExp = tokenExp(refreshToken);

          // console.log(accessToken)

          //referesh는 쿠키로, access는 활용할수 있도록 client로 보낸다.
          sendCookie(res, refreshToken);

          // console.log(req.exp, req.user, "req.exp");

          return res.status(200).send({
            data: {
              id: userId,
              nickname: userNick,
              username: userUsername,
              social_user:false,
              isAdmin:false,
              accessExp: accessExp,
              refreshExp: refreshExp,
            },
            accessToken: accessToken,
          });

          // 토큰 생성 한다. 구글, 카카오 인경우도 있으므로 id이용
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
```

postman setting & result

raw JSON
{
"username": "123456",
"password": "123456456"
}

content-type: application/json

```
"data": {
    "id": 1,
    "nickname": "123456",
    "username": "123456456",
    "social_user": false,
    "isAdmin": false,
    "accessExp": 1658500545,
    "refreshExp": 1658748945
},
"accessToken": " "
```

}

Comment: If the problem is on the server, I think it would be good to include server code in the question

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, when you observe the HTTP request on the network tab, does the request contain the expected body?

Comment: you also seem to have one redundant closing `}` after headers object. EDIT. actually you have to put it before last comma and not after

Comment: Can you please verify in postman are you sending data in formdata or json?

Comment: @JaromandaX well I'm pretty sure it is :D Depends on server-side code, but if content type header is required on back-end, it simply doesn't get send due to syntax error, most probably as the whole request

Comment: @JSEvgeny - the code parses up until the very last `}` ... but in the `headers` area it's fine :p the layout is ugly, but the code is OK there

Comment: @JaromandaX might be, nevermind then :) It's really funny though to look for other people possible syntax error here, rather than they would use a proper IDE and formatter...

Comment: It's really difficult to tell what could be wrong, codewise looks okay, the only concern I have is about this one `}` that I've already told about. Next step would be to check from your browser Network tab what axios sends to the backend and what response it gets back